# stackplot legend issue when there is a secondary subplot for Matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Here is my code and below it is the error produced.

My legend appears, but only one of the lines is in it.
The stacked subplot labels do not appear.

```
import xlrd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

file_location = "/Users/adampatel/Desktop/psw02.xls"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Data 1')

x = [worksheet.cell_value(i+1425, 0) for i in range(worksheet.nrows-1425)]
y1 = [worksheet.cell_value(i+1425, 1) for i in range(worksheet.nrows-1425)]
y2 = [worksheet.cell_value(i+1425, 25) for i in range(worksheet.nrows-1425)]
y3 = [worksheet.cell_value(i+1425, 35) for i in range(worksheet.nrows-1425)]
y4 = [worksheet.cell_value(i+1425, 41) for i in range(worksheet.nrows-1425)]
y5 = [worksheet.cell_value(i+1425, 50) for i in range(worksheet.nrows-1425)]


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

start_date = datetime.date(1899, 12, 30)
dates=[start_date + datetime.timedelta(xval) for xval in x]
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator((), bymonthday=1, interval=6))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator((), bymonthday=1, interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b'%y"))

ly1 = ax.plot(dates, y1, '-k', label = 'Oil Intake (LHS)')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ly2 = ax2.stackplot(dates, y2, y3, y4, y5, colors=['0.2','0.4','0.6','0.8'], label=['gasoline', 'kerosene', 'distillates', 'residuals'])

ly1y2 = ly1+ly2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in ly1y2]
ax.legend(ly1y2, labs, fontsize = 10, loc = 2)

ax.set_ylim(11500,17500)
ax2.set_ylim(8000, 28000)
plt.show()

=================== RESTART: /Users/adampatel/Desktop/1.py ===================

Warning (from warnings module):
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/legend.py", line 613
(str(orig_handle),))
UserWarning: Legend does not support <matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection    object at 0x10b292590>
Use proxy artist instead.
```

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist

Comment: Here is how you create a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I thought about it and googled a few solutions.  Here are the lines of code that I used.

```
import xlrd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import datetime

file_location = "/Users/adampatel/Desktop/psw02.xls"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location, on_demand = False)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Data 1')

x = [worksheet.cell_value(i+1425, 0) for i in range(worksheet.nrows-1425)]
y1 = [worksheet.cell_value(i+1425, 1) for i in range(worksheet.nrows-1425)]
y2 = [worksheet.cell_value(i+1425, 25) for i in range(worksheet.nrows-1425)]
y3 = [worksheet.cell_value(i+1425, 35) for i in range(worksheet.nrows-1425)]
y4 = [worksheet.cell_value(i+1425, 41) for i in range(worksheet.nrows-1425)]
y5 = [worksheet.cell_value(i+1425, 50) for i in range(worksheet.nrows-1425)]


fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

start_date = datetime.date(1899, 12, 30)
dates=[start_date + datetime.timedelta(xval) for xval in x]
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator((), bymonthday=1, interval=6))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator((), bymonthday=1, interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b'%y"))

ly1, = ax.plot(dates, y1, '-k', linewidth=2.0, label = 'Oil Intake (LHS)')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ly2 = ax2.stackplot(dates, y2, y3, y4, y5, colors=['0.2','0.4','0.6','0.8'], label=['gasoline', 'kerosene', 'distillates', 'residuals'])


ax.grid()
ax.set_ylabel("Thousands of Barrels per Day")
ax2.set_ylabel("Thousands of Barrels per Day")
ax.set_ylim(11500,17500)
ax2.set_ylim(8000, 28000)
plt.legend([ly1, mpatches.Patch(color='.2'), mpatches.Patch(color='.4'), mpatches.Patch(color='.6'), mpatches.Patch(color='.8')], ['Oil Intake (LHS)', 'Gasoline','Kerosene','Distillates', 'Residuals'], loc = 2)
plt.title('Refinar-Blendar Intake')
plt.savefig('Refinar Blendar2.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=90)
plt.show()
```